# solving a system of inequalities where the solution is infeasible

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, nonlinear-optimization, mystic

I am trying to solve the attached a non-linear optimization problem. I would like to give mystic a try, since SciPy.optimize does not work as expected (further details below).

[image: Optimization problem formulation]

Because c_1 = 3, the problem is infeasible. This is because (p_1 - 3 - 0.22) / p_1 < 0.05 means that p_1 would have to be larger than 3.22 which would conflict with p_1 / 2.2 <= 0.65.

There exists an *unanswered* question addressing the fundamental problem of SciPy successfully terminating for infeasible problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568164/scipy-optimize-terminates-successfully-for-infeasible-nlp). Unfortunately, I need this specific problem solved with python, which is why I am trying my luck here again.

When I used SciPy.optimize, the program also terminated successfully, breaking the constraints without raising an issue (even when setting keep_feasible=True). My problem is larger and other constraints could not be met, either. Accordingly, SciPy appears to be the wrong tool for the job.

My first question: am I doing anything wrong?
If not: Are there any alternatives to SciPy.optimize? I have also been looking into mystic, but not been able to get it to work at all.

I know this is a rather specific problem, so my thanks to everyone who wants to chip in. Finally, my apologies if I have offended any mathematicians with the probably incorrect formulation of the problem.

Comment: I'm the `mystic` author.  I believe `mystic` should be able to handle this problem for you.  I'll try and post something below later, unless someone beats me to the punch.  I did however, post an answer to [the question you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568164), and I'll can point you to [an example in mystic for infeasible solutions](https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples2/no_solution3.py).

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I was fixing a bug that was relevant to this question... thus, you will need to get the very latest `mystic` out of GitHub to see the same results.

Comment: Looks to me like a small Linear Programming (LP) problem. There are numerous solvers for this (and they will detect infeasible models).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: please feel free to make some suggestions that will work, and post a solution... for example, using CONOPT and IPOPT.

Comment: Sorry, looks like nonlinear obj with linear constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a difficult problems, since it requires solving a system of symbolic inequality equations with denominators.  A symbolic solve with inequalities with denominators is tricky because multiplying by the denominator can flip the sign of the inequality, depending on the value of the yet-unknown variable.  Solving one of these alone is difficult... but then adding in that the solution is infeasible makes it even worse.  So, bear in mind that the following is a bit shaky... but it's probably the close to the best you can do to approach this problem directly.

```
>>> def objective(x):
...   x0,x1,x2 = x
...   return (x0 - 3 - .23)/x0 + (x1 - 1.17 - .23)/x1 + (x2 - 0.71 - .23)/x2
...
>>> def cost(x): # maximize
...   return -objective(x)
...
>>> bounds = [(None,.65*2.2),(None,.65*2.9),(None,.65*1.91)]
>>>
>>> equations = '''
... (x0 - 3.00 - .23)/(38000 * x0) >= .05
... (x1 - 1.17 - .23)/(33000 * x1) >= .05
... (x2 - 0.71 - .23)/(29000 * x2) >= .05
... (38000 * x0 + 33000 * x1 + 29000 * x2) / (38000 * (2.2 - x0) + 33000 * (2.9 - x1) + 29000 * (1.91 - x2)) <= -0.5
... (38000 * (2.2 - x0) + 33000 * (2.9 - x1) + 29000 * (1.91 - x2)) / (38000 * x0 + 33000 * x1 + 29000 * x2) >= 0.18
... '''
>>> from mystic.solvers import diffev2
>>> from mystic.symbolic import generate_constraint, generate_solvers, simplify
```

That should set up the problem... now to the tricky part.  Simplify the equations, and then solve.

```
>>> eqn = simplify(equations)
>>> cf = generate_constraint(generate_solvers(eqn))
>>> result = diffev2(cost, x0=bounds, bounds=bounds, constraints=cf, npop=40, gtol=50, disp=True, full_output=True)
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded
>>> print(result[1])
inf
```

We see that we get `inf`, which is an indication that `mystic` is running into an infeasible solution.  But, I'm glossing over some stuff above, and was a bit lucky, actually.  Let's look at the simplified equation.

```
>>> print(eqn)
x0 > 0
x0 > -0.868421052631579*x1 - 0.763157894736842*x2 + 6.17605263157895
x2 >= -0.000648723257418910
x1 >= -0.000848999393571862
x0 >= -0.868421052631579*x1 - 0.763157894736842*x2 - 6.17605263157895
x2 < 0
x1 < 0
x0 < -33*x1/38 - 29*x2/38
x0 <= -0.00170089520800421
x0 >= -0.868421052631579*x1 - 0.763157894736842*x2 + 5.23394290811775
```

That's only one possible of the several simplified equations, due to the denominators and inequalities, as mentioned above... it just happened to be the *right* one.  We can get *all* of the candidate simplified equations, as follows:

```
>>> all_eqn = simplify(equations, all=True)
>>> len(all_eqn)
32
```

Note we have 32 possibilities -- some of which are "good", and some aren't -- depending on the values of the variables.  You can plug `all_eqn` into `cf = generate_constraint(generate_solvers(all_eqn))`, and then `mystic` will do it's best to find the solution that minimizes all the possible simplified equations.  This typically works *ok*... and I'm sure may fail.  The situations gets worse with there being a maximization, and more importantly, the solution you are looking for is infeasible.

I'm going to say that this is an area of active development, and `mystic` could use some improvement to handle cases like this better.

**EDIT:** In the solution above, I forgot use the keyword `join`.  The default is `join=None` which applies each equation sequentially.  While this is faster, it's not what you want if there's conflicting equations.  I should probably have used:

```
>>> from mystic.constraints import and_
>>> cf = generate_constraint(generate_solvers(eqn), join=and_)
```

which should better ensure that all constraints are respected.

Comment: Wow Mike, mystic handles this problem far better than SciPy currently does. This looks exactly like what I was looking for! Thank you so much!